# Why loading a model takes so much time for me in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining

For a personal project I need to run several machine learning algorithms against different texts in order to classify them.

I used to do this using RapidMiner but I decided to move all my development to R as I feel I have more control with it.

The issue I am seeing now (which I did not notice with RapidMiner) is that loading the models is taking a lot of time.

**For example:**

I have a model which checks if it the text refers to sports. 
The model is `37.7 MB` and it takes `8:34` with my `2.2 GH i7 Mac with 4GB of RAM`

**The way I am calling the model is the following:**

```
fileNameMatrix = paste(query,query1,"-matrix.Rd", sep ="")
fileNameModel= paste(query,query1,"-model.Rd", sep ="")

load(fileNameMatrix)
load(fileNameModel)
```

The model was generated using `RTextTools`

Those query variables you read are because I need to call almost 20 models and compare them against different datasets. That is why although 8 minutes is not a lot, when I read all of them its almost 3 hours just on loading which makes my task almost useless considering its an almost real time task.

Which factors should I consider to reduce loading time if reducing the size of the model is not an option?

One other thing I consider suspicious is that while the matrix file is rather small `64KB` the model is still `37.7MB`. Is it possible that the model file is bigger than necessary? Have anyone experienced something similar using RTextTools?

This is one of my firsts tasks using models in R so excuse me if I am doing somethings which is obviously wrong.

Thanks a lot for your time and any tip in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the RAM usage in your Activity Monitor? Compressed `RData` files are relatively tiny, but they uncompress to be massive. For instance, an `n x n` matrix of all `0`'s will take up essentially no space for any `n` (that may explain your small matrix size).  Your loaded model might then be huge; I have some `RData` files that amount to maybe `200 MB` but that cannot be loaded in memory in `R`. This could become a problem if you're running low on RAM, as your computer may attempt to use drive space to load the files.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking on running it from a clean reboot and verify RAM. I did notice during the execution that CPU spikes and the goes back to almost nothing for a while but I have to verify the RAM. Regarding your other point, do you know if there is a way to verify the final size of a compressed Rdata file? Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: I did some tests before rebooting and this might be the issue. R went from 70mb to 1.42GB after loading the model (and thats just 1 of the 20 models). So this means that either the model is wrongly formatted and producing a huge file with lots of unnecessary data as @ozjimbob suggested or..I need to buy more RAM :(

Comment: If your model is very large that huge of a jump is not uncommon. If a lot of your data is easily compressible then it's normal. Just to check, save your stuff into an uncompressed file using the `compress=FALSE` option. I can't think of any good way to determine if the model is the issue, maybe find a saved model online (in `RData`), recreate it yourself, save it, and compare sizes?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to save the model uncompressed and it was 1.95GB! so I guess that might answer my question. Now I have to find a way to reduce the size or move to a faster machine.

Comment: I ran into exactly this problem very recently and upgraded my late 2011 MacBook Pro to 8 `GB` RAM, which costs ~$40 and is extremely easy to install. Good luck in your project!

Comment: Thanks, I been considering using Amazon EMR and after this I will definitely will take a better look at it. Thanks so much for all your help

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the model output from RTextTools, but it's pretty common for a model object to be significantly larger than the input data frame.  For example, the output of a **glm** contain all the input data, as well as predicted values, residuals, coefficients, errors, you name it.  The output of a **RandomForest** model contains the input data as well as definitions for thousands of trees etc.

How does the loading time of the models compare to running them from scratch?  Have you looked at what's *in* the model object to see what it contains, with the possibility of pruning off any statistics you don't need?

```
str(fileNameModel)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast response. This is getting strange. I run str() and it took almost 3 hours to complete! I think the best I can do is re train the algorithms one by one and check which is/are the ones causing the problem. As for the str() I don't see anything in there which would justify all this loading time.